# Setting properties on option from select list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to add to an existing script that was created by another developer. The aim is to show an item from a dropdownlist in some instances and hide in others. I added a bit of code and I realised I have been told that what i am trying to select does not exist. Here is what I have running?

```
var menuNav = document.getElementById("Dir_Drop");
var MenuVal = menuNav.options[menuNav.selectedIndex].value;


menuNav.options["member"].show();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dir-dropdown"  >   
 <select id="Dir_Drop">
     <option value="">-- Navigate Here --</option>
 <?php if ($pageOrg->getShowTabsMembers() == "1"){ ?>
     <option value="member" onchange="return ClearPrintQueue();">Members</option>
 <?php } ?>  
 <?php if ($pageOrg->getShowTabsFamilies() == "1"){ ?> 
     <option value="family" onchange="return ClearPrintQueue();">Families</option>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($pageOrg->getShowTabsGroups() == "1"){ ?> 
     <option value="group" onchange="return ClearPrintQueue();">Groups</option>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($pageOrg->getShowTabsChurchStaff() == "1"){ ?>  
     <option value="staff" onchange="return ClearPrintQueue();">Church Staff</option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```

The error I see in firefox is: "TypeError: menuNav.options.family is undefined"

I would greatly appreciate any input towards the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `options` takes an `index` -- not the current text. You will have to iterate and find the current text like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuNav.options.length; i++) {
    if (menuNav.options[i].text == "Members") {
        //found the index with text "Members" -- do logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the modified code I have: for (var i = 0; i < menuNav.options.length; i++) {if (menuNav.options[i].text == "Members"){menuNav.options[i].show();}. The current error associated with it: TypeError: menuNav.options[i].show is not a function

Comment: Also: TypeError: menuNav.options.member is undefined

Comment: Well there is no method `.show` for `options` -- you probably want to change the `style` or completed remove/add it

Comment: so in essence: menuNav.options[i].style.display='none';

Comment: also say I want to check the selected options value. I had this: var menuNav = document.getElementById("Dir_Drop");
 var MenuVal = menuNav.options[menuNav.selectedIndex].value; if(MenuVal == "group"){
      
         listtype = "grp";
    }